# NextJS ISR unlimited reload page when deployed to Vercel

Tags: javascript, node.js, next.js, vercel, static-site-generation

I have a problem that my website being deployed to Vercel with NextJS ISR.  When I use getStaticPaths.  The website will reload unlimited when I click to getStaticPaths that page.
Only getStaticProps will not make this error.  I am using the hobby plan.  Everything works when I am on localhost and use "npm run build and start".

here is my code:

```
export async function getStaticProps({ params: { slug } }) {
  const res = await fetch(`${API_URL}/post/${slug}`);
  const posts = await res.json();

  return {
    props: {
      posts,

    },
    // Next.js will attempt to re-generate the page:
    revalidate: 10, // In seconds
  };
}

export async function getStaticPaths() {
  // this URL is created specifically for fetch first time of ISR
  // My first post will unlimited reload**********
  const res = await fetch(`${API_URL}/postforisrfirst`);
  // const res = await fetch(`${API_URL}/post`);
  const posts = await res.json();

  // Get the paths we want to pre-render based on posts
  const paths = posts.map((post) => ({
    params: { slug: post.slug },
  }));


  return { paths, fallback: "blocking" };
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by _"The website will reload unlimited when I click to getStaticPaths that page"_? `getStaticPaths` gets called once at build time. Do you get any errors when building the app in Vercel?

Comment: The console show two errors:
(1)Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()

(2)Failed to load resource: net::ERR_HTTP2_SERVER_REFUSED_STREAM

Mostly, when the auto-reload for few times and waits for half hour, it will return normally.  However, it is annoyed that it will happen after every times deploy to Vercel.